# HttpClient's PutAsync behaving differently than a manual PUT request (via PostMan)

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm trying to create a PUT request to an external API, with an array of integers as request body. When posting to the external API in question directly through PostMan (Chrome extension), it works fine. Here is the request:

```
PUT /rest/*****?skipconfig=true HTTP/1.1
Host: ******:****
Authorization: Basic **********
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache

[1214186,1214052,1214333,1213983,1214332,1214332]
```

However, when I try to create that same request with .NET's HttpClient, the external API throws a Server error 500 after about 10 seconds, making me suspect that the HttpClient has altered the request in some obscure way, that makes the external API read the request wrong. Here is my sample code:

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intArray);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", SvcCredentials);

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; charset=utf-8").MediaType); 

    // List data response.
    var uri = new Uri(BaseUrl + "/rest/*****?skipconfig=true", UriKind.Absolute);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Parse the response body.
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().ToString();
    }
    throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

What am I missing here? I've tried envoking the PutAsync method with both URI object and URL-string.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler or similar to capture the request you're sending so that you can compare it to your manual one?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought about that, but I'm having a bit of difficulty with that part, since the request is made with https, and my network knowledge fails me at that point

Comment: @unarity the error thrown from the external API is a raw HTTP-status with not message, sadly.

Comment: Looks like request doesn't come to the application, it is probably rejected by iis. Do you use https trough postman as well?

Comment: @unarity Yes, I do.

Comment: What happens when you try to `await client.PutAsync` instead?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Same thing happens. Which makes sense since the request is made to the server in both instances, and await does not have anything to do with the content of the request.

Comment: @MichaelCleverly It doesn't ,but I thought there might be a blocking issue which causes something to timeout.

Comment: Solved by using the NuGet package "RestSharp" instead of .NET's HttpClient. Still don't know what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found the cause of this issue.

After doing a bit of research, I was able to decrypt the HTTPS request, using a simple option in fiddler.

As it turns out, `StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; charset=utf-8").MediaType);` adds a "Content-Length" header behind the scenes. This header was the cause of the server error in the other end (don't ask me why).